# json request into string

Tags: json, string

I have the following json structure:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "number": 123,
            "animal": "mush"
        },
        {
            "number": "123",
            "animal": ""
        }
    ],
    "animal_id": 1
}
```

How can I save it as a string?

Comment: What language you work with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Json to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064385/parse-json-to-string)

Answer (score 2):

It varies by language, but in JavaScript (which *might* be likely used in your case), [JSON.stringify does this job.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: use JSON.parse for the reverse, from string into a proper object